# MGTwitterEngine is not returning re-tweets, only “original” tweets

Tags: iphone, twitter, mgtwitterengine

I’m a newbie to iPhone app development and trying to create a Twitter-based iPhone app.
I’m using `MGTwitterEngine` to search and retrieve the timeline of people I follow.
The method I’m using is:

```
[twitterEngine getFollowedTimelineSinceID:0 startingAtPage:0 count:100];
```

Things are working great, however there are a couple of things I struggle with:

1. I’m only getting tweets originally posted by my followed list, no re-tweets at all. I would really like to get all tweets (original and re-tweets) at the same call, but if I need to perform two requests (one for tweets and one for re-tweets) that will work fine for me as well.
2. I’m getting back less than 100 tweets, though I know for a fact that people I follow have posted more than that. Any idea how to solve it?

Several people have mentioned `MGTwitterEngine` is lacking re-tweeting functionality. I’m not trying to re-tweet but simply to get the complete timeline (including re-tweets by people I follow).

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you taken a look at the MG source to see what api call it is making for getFollowed... I would do that, then look at the twitter API docs to make sure retweets are even supposed to come back in that call.

Comment: Thanks shawnwall, I'll take a look at the actual api call performed by getFollowed. Regarding the Twitter API - it looks like the Twitter API does support fetching of retweets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/home_timeline

Specifically look at the part that say :

```
Include_RTS : When set to either true, t or 1,the timeline will contain native retweets (if they exist) in addition to the standard stream of tweets...
```

Now in the getFollowedTimelineSinceID method you'll need to create a new object for the params dictionary something along these lines

`[params setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"true"] forKey:@"Include_RTS"];`

Comment: Thanks @bizsytes worked like a charm.
Per your suggestion I have done two modifications to  getFollowedTimelineSinceID:
1. Changed the path string from @statuses/friends_timeline.%@ to @statuses/home_timeline.%@
2. Added the Include_RTS object 

Apparently it solved both my problems (retweets & number of statuses retrieved).

Comment: oh yea I kinda didn't say anything about the friend_timeline being deprecated since that wasn't the original question. +1 for figuring that out all by yourself :) Plus you can add any other param just like that, for example you might add one to know if you've retweeted a particular tweet. The retweeted param returned by default is always false and there's another workaround to find out if the tweet has been retweeted by you.

Answer (score 0):

Per @bizsytes suggestion I have done two modifications to MGTwitterEngine’s
getFollowedTimelineSinceID method:

1. Changed the path string from @statuses/friends_timeline.%@ to @statuses/home_timeline.%@
2. Added the Include_RTS object

Apparently it solved both my problems (retweets & number of statuses retrieved).

Now the method now looks like the following:

```
- (NSString *)getAllFollowedTimelineSinceID:(unsigned long)sinceID withMaximumID:(unsigned long)maxID startingAtPage:(int)page count:(int)count
{
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"statuses/home_timeline.%@", API_FORMAT];

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:0];
    if (sinceID > 0) {
        [params setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", sinceID] forKey:@"since_id"];
    }
    if (maxID > 0) {
        [params setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", maxID] forKey:@"max_id"];
    }
    if (page > 0) {
        [params setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", page] forKey:@"page"];
    }
    if (count > 0) {
        [params setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", count] forKey:@"count"];
    }

    [params setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"true"] forKey:@"Include_RTS"];


    return [self _sendRequestWithMethod:nil path:path queryParameters:params body:nil 
                            requestType:MGTwitterFollowedTimelineRequest 
                           responseType:MGTwitterStatuses];
}
```